# Calling method in glkView DrawInRect causes EXC BAD ACCESS error

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es

```
#pragma mark - GLKViewDelegate

- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {

    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    [self.effect prepareToDraw];
    [self.model Render];
}
```

Whenever I call `[self.model Render]` (A custom method that as of now does nothing) inside of

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
```

It causes a **thread 1 exc_bad_access (code=1 address=0x10)** error, I'll be happy to share more of my source but won't in case it's something simple that this much information can resolve.

Comment: Did you try adding a breakpoint on that line where you call `[self.model Render]`? Then, see if self.model actually exists and is not nil.

Comment: @SimonGermain `self.model` being `nil` would have just caused the method not be called. Anyway it would be nice to see the `render` code. Also please use lowercase names for methods signatures.

Comment: Like I said it currently does nothing, I commented out the code I had before to see if it was broken.

Comment: You're missing glFlush() .

Comment: Also, if it's crashing on thread 1, that means it's crashing on a background thread, otherwise, thread 0 would be crashing. Are you running anything on a background thread?

Comment: It flushes the OpenGL-ES buffer, try it.

Comment: @SimonGermain Not that I know off.

Comment: I can upload a Xcode project file, comment if you'd be willing to take a look.

Comment: what modifiers did you put for the model property? how are you setting it's value?

Comment: also why Render and not render

Comment: 1. @property (assign) VModel *model; 
self.model = [[VModel alloc] VModelWithArray:array];
2. Because it looks better.

Comment: Shit! By changing it to (strong, nonatomic) it fixed my problem, where can i find the specification of these to avoid using it incorrectly in the future.